# How to reset areas layout without losing data?

Tags: interface

Suppose I resized, duplicated, closed and created numerous areas in Blender. Now how can I return back? If I choose `File - Defaults - Load factory settings` I will not only restore layout, but also drop any objects in the scene.

How to restore layout only?

Comment: Hey :). Why not just add a new workspace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the project.

Go to the top menu and select: File>New to open an empty file with the default layout.

Again on the File Menu, select "File Open", when the window to select files appears press <kbd>N</kbd>  (or press the gear icon on the top right) to open the options tab.

Uncheck "load UI" and then select your file and open it.

[image]

The file should now open with the default user interface and layout.

I'm the future you can avoid creating a messy interface by using a layout instead of subdividing windows.